# Adding a Categorylist to all pages with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new with MVC4 and just MVC.

I have a `homecontroller` and a `categorycontroller`. The `categorycontroller` sends data from the model to the `categoryIndex` view. That's works fine.

But now I want to add the `categorylist` on all the available controllers.

I already fixed this to add in all classes `return view(db.categorys.ToList());` and add `categoryIndex` to the shared folder. In `_layout.cshtml` I'm adding a@RenderPage("~/")` and this works.

But when I have to pass more than only the `(db.categorys.ToList())` in the return it goes wrong.

How can I fixed this problem. How do I add the categorylist too every controller and page properly?

Comment: What goes wrong? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Add `CategoryList` collection as a property to your ViewModels( of all pages). You can add that to a base class and inherit from that also.

```
public class Category
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
}
public class BasePageViewModel
{
  public List<Category> CategoryList { set;get;}

  BasePageViewModel()
  {
    CategoryList=new List<Category>();
  }
}
```

Now you can inherit from this base class for other view models.

```
public class ProductViewModel : BasePageViewModel
{
  public string ProductName { set;get;}
  //Other properties
}
```

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to ProductViewModel, you can call Html.Partial to show the `CategoryList` partial view.

```
@model ProductViewModel
<h3>This page is for product @Model.ProductName</h3>
@Html.Partial(Model.CategoryList)
```

Assuming you have a partial view to render the CategoryList

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest throwing commonly used things, such as a category list, into the ViewBag.  This will allow you some separation and only returning to the view what needs to be there.  Hope this helped!